# Usage of laravel middleware for request, but not for jobs/batch

Tags: laravel

I see that a lot of code and tutorials are using laravel for differente bussines calls: like authorization, log activitiy,etc.

What happens when some of your tasks are run in a cron, in a name of user? You can call call the services that you are using in the Controllers, but you are missing code that runs when you have a a request?

How should you split your code to be able to run your servicess/task from controllers, but also from a job resolves or a bash script?

Comment: Is task scheduling what you are looking for? https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling

Comment: Scheduling is the context which  I refer to. using schedules and commands your are missing the business from the middleware. How do you bring that busines also into commands